# How to fix IPython display bug in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, jupyter, ipython

I am trying to display different IPython.display HTML objects in different notebook cells.

When I run this code in a cell, it renders properly:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import ipywidgets
out_1 = ipywidgets.Output()
with out_1:
    display(HTML(filename="echarts.html"))
out_1
```

[image]

But when I run this code in the next cell, it "displays" incorrectly in the first cell:

```
out_2 = ipywidgets.Output()
with out_2:
    display(HTML(filename="echarts2.html"))
out_2
```

[image]

While it doesn't display at all on its cell:

[image]

To get the expected behavior, I need to "Clear All Outputs", run the second cell first, and then the first one. Then things display properly.

[image]

But if I run either cell again. Things break. No idea what's going on.

I've tried rendering plain html without any JavaScript. This works. Display also works after clearing and running the second cell first. But it just works the first time I run second cell and then first cell. If I run either cell again, things break. I can't figure out if the problem is VS Code or IPython. I've tried running this in Jupyter Lab and it won't work.

Comment: I'd suggest that you raise an issue ticket. Use the `Help > Raise Issue` menu item. Once you've done that, please add a link in your question here to your issue ticket.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it appears that VS Code and ipywidgets have some weird interactions. The charts had the same div ids, thus the linked behavior. I changed the div ids to something unique on each chart and weird behavior stopped.

Comment: what were the IDs? Did they correspond in any way to the code you wrote or the files your code loaded?